# Text file download link (ruby on rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, download, href, text-files

I want to add a download link to my html page. Download will be a .txt file. I have done this,

```
<a href="path_to_file/myfile.txt">click to download txt </a>
```

But the problem is, when a user clicks this link, instead of asking user to download the file, it simply shows the text in the browser.

How can I change this script to ask user to download the file (with the default download prompt dialog box)

UPDATE: Thanks all for the replies. I'm using ruby/rails on the server side.

Comment: You need to set the appropriate HTTP headers, thus you cannot do it with plain HTML. Do you have access to a server-side tool to change HTTP headers, such as PHP or Apache's `.htaccess` files?

Comment: The browser will display the txt file by default, unless you send a Content-Disposition: attachment header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use rails [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) method

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget set wright content-header at server side:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"myfile.txt\"");
```

Comment: I quess in ruby it would be #### response.content_disposition = "attachment"; response.filename = "myfile.txt" ####

Answer (score 0):

1. simple way - zip it.
2. if is available php

```
header ( 'Content-Type: text/html');
header ( "Content-Disposition: 'attachment'; filename='text.txt'" );
include ('path_to_file/myfile.txt')
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in .htaccess

1. If you want only for this specific file:

```
<Directory path_to_file>
    <Files myfile.txt>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            ForceType application/octet-stream
            Header set Content-Disposition attachment
        </IfModule>
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

2. If you want it to be for all the `.txt` files under `path_to_file`

```
<Directory path_to_file>
    <FilesMatch “.(?i:(txt))$”>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            ForceType application/octet-stream
            Header set Content-Disposition attachment
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

View : (Html file)

= link_to 'click to download txt', :controller => 'download', :action => 'test'

Download Controller :

def test
**file_path = 'path_to_file/myfile.txt'
send_file file_path**
end

Answer (score -2):

If your server supports php, you could use these lines:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="name.txt"');
readfile('name.txt');
```

Also see [PHP: header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) Example #1